# Add javascript function in the checkbox in CgridView in yii

Tags: checkbox, yii, cgridview

I encountered a problem when I tried to pass a value into a js function when using `checkbox` in `CgridView` in yii. The UI is as shown below:

[image]

I want that when I click the checkbox and the javascript function to update data in database should be called as shown below:

```
(example : 'onclick'=> "fn_onclick($data->id);")
```

But, looks like it doesn't work.

The code:

```
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'assign-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'header'=>'is_admin', 
            'name'=>'check',
            'id'=>'select',
            'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
            'checked'=>'0',
            'htmlOptions'=>array(
                'style'=>'text-align: center',
                'onclick'=> "fn_onclick($data->id);"
            ),
        )
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly doesn't work?

The onclick attribute isn't parsed by the evaluateExpression function, like you can see here, https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.17/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CCheckBoxColumn.php#L220

So you should probably approach this in a different way. or Extend the CCheckBoxColumn and add you're own functionality

```
$rawData = [
    ['id'=>1,'email'=>'foo','username'=>'foo@bar.nl','is_admin'=>0],
    ['id'=>2,'email'=>'bar','username'=>'bar@foo.nl','is_admin'=>0],
    ['id'=>3,'email'=>'foobar','username'=>'foobar@barfoo.nl','is_admin'=>0]
];

$dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($rawData, array(
    'id'=>'user',
    'sort'=>array(
        'attributes'=>array(
            'id', 'username', 'email',
        ),
    ),
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>10,
    ),
));

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'assign-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'selectionChanged' => 'js:function() { selectionChanged() }', // listen to selection changed
    'rowHtmlOptionsExpression' => 'array("id"=>"row-".$data["id"],"data-username"=>$data["username"])', // if you're using a object this should be $data->id
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'username',
        'email',
        array(
            'header'=>'is_admin',
            'name'=>'check',
            'id'=>'select',
            'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
            'checked'=>'0',
            'htmlOptions'=>array(
                'style'=>'text-align: center',
            ),
        ),

    ),
));
?>

<script type="application/javascript">
    function selectionChanged(){
        var ids = $('#assign-grid').yiiGridView('getChecked', 'select');
        for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            var id = ids[i];
            console.log("user: "+ $('#row-'+id).attr('data-username') + " is admin"); // retrieve the data attribute
        }
    }
</script>
```

Update so that the header won't be a checkbox

```
class ECheckBoxColumn extends CCheckBoxColumn
{
    //...
    public $headerCheckbox = false;
    //...

    public function getHeaderCellContent()
    {
        if(trim($this->headerTemplate)==='')
            return $this->grid->blankDisplay;
        if($this->selectableRows===null && $this->grid->selectableRows>1 && $this->$headerCheckbox)
            $item=CHtml::checkBox($this->id.'_all',false,array('class'=>'select-on-check-all'));
        elseif($this->selectableRows>1 && $this->$headerCheckbox)
            $item=CHtml::checkBox($this->id.'_all',false);
        else
            $item=parent::getHeaderCellContent();
        return strtr($this->headerTemplate,array(
            '{item}'=>$item,
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: many thanks for your information!  actually I want to pass ID and other arguments to the JS function(ex: fn_onclick($row_id, $row_name...)) could you please teach me or any example for me reference? I'm a new for Yii now. BTW, I use Yii1 now.

Comment: You can use the selectionChanged (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#selectionChanged-detail) listener and the data attributes to achieve what you want. i've added an example in my original post

Comment: thank you.  It's strange that no sure it can't work on my side. maybe it's because I'm using YII1? For testing purpose, I add like this: 'selectionChanged'=>'function(id) {alert("test"); }', but I can't get the "test" and no any error

Comment: ok could you try it like this  'selectionChanged'=>'js:function(id) {alert("test"); }'. the "js:" prefix tells yii that what follows is pure JS code and should not be escaped

Comment: Hi, it's the same.  the code: $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
 'id'=>'assign-grid',
 'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
 'selectionChanged' => 'js:function(id){alert("test");}', // listen to selection

Comment: Hi, yes it appears to work fine. i tested it on Yii1.1.16 and my jquery version is v1.11.1. You could try to set the selectablerows attribute to see if that makes any difference (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCheckBoxColumn#selectableRows-detail)

Comment: Hi, it works fine for using selectablerows, it's strange why it can't work for selectionChanged?

Comment: Hi Tim,  I found the problem that indeed it's due to the Yii/jquery version. After I updated it and then the function selectionChanged can work now. but it's not my want(now looks only one checkbox can be checked at the same time, I would like to I can click the checkbox for each row or  there are more than 1 checkbox in one row); I try to add 'selectableRows', but the header name will be replaced by checkbox when set it to 2, but actually I would like to use name actually, is it any way to achieve?

Comment: Yes it is possible but I see no other option then to extend the CCheckBoxColumn and override the getHeaderCellContent function (https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.17/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CCheckBoxColumn.php#L196). I added a code sample to my original anwser